# How do I get the numpad to work in vim using iterm2 on osx with term=xterm?

Tags: macos, vim, xterm, iterm2

My numpad works in iterm2 (bash), but it inserts characters instead of numbers in insert mode for vim.

How can I get vim to recognise the correct escape codes.

I have tried editing the escape codes as suggested here without any luck:
http://code.google.com/p/iterm2/issues/detail?id=702

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Looks like the answer is to go into Preferences->Profiles->Keys and load preset of: "xterm with Numeric Keypad".

Comment: I didn't have this preset, so in [my answer](http://superuser.com/a/939832/121441) I explained how you can add these shortcuts yourself.

Comment: It appears that the preset no longer exists in iTerm 2.1.1

Comment: Recently did a new OS install.  The preset is still there in iTerm 2.1.1.

Comment: Works in iTerm 2.1.4 too, though I also had to add a new shortcut to insert hex key code 0xd for NumPad's Enter key to work. (Weirdly not detected as the Num-⏎ key already registered, but as ⏎ on its own, when set up.)

Comment: Works for me. I'm using iTerm2 Build 2.1.4.

Comment: Latest beta, preset's gone (again?).

Answer (score 22):

For me the solution was disabling `VT100 Application Keypad-Mode` in `Preferences > Profiles > Advanced`.

Comment: This solution works only on the native terminal, but not with iTerm

Answer (score 14):

You can add global keyboard shortcuts in Preferences -> Keys and map the numpad characters to "Send Text" actions to send the text they are supposed to send.

[image: iTerm2 keys preferences]

Comment: For the `Enter` key, choose the `Send Hex Codes` action and enter `0x0D`.

Answer (score 8):

but it removes some colors in my vim.

if you just need it some times, just type:

```
:set term=ansi
```

in VIM

Best regards