# How do I use windows style Home and End on OSX in Vim (iterm2)

Tags: macos, vim, key-binding, iterm2

Having tried many options to replicate Home, End functionality (for beginning of line and end of line), from windows to OSX, I have got to the point where it works everywhere except in vim.  I am using iterm2 on OSX.

I have tried editing my .vimrc and vim seems to ignore the presets for the rest of the system.

How do I remap home and end in vim to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having resolved an issue with my numpad here:

[How do I get the numpad to work in vim using iterm2 on osx with term=xterm?](https://superuser.com/questions/565178/how-do-i-get-the-numpad-to-work-in-vim-using-iterm2-on-osx-with-term-xterm/565179#565179)

I decided to use the same hack and found that if you go to Preferences -> Profiles -> Keys -> Load preset of xterm with numeric keypad and then change the shortcut for Shift HOME, press HOME.  Change the shortcut for Shift END, press END.

Comment: Escape sequence [1;2H for home and [1;2F for end.