# iTerm2: Numeric keypad enter does not get mapped to <CR>

Tags: macos, keyboard, terminal, iterm2

I've set up iTerm2 to map numpad keys to send correct xterm key codes as suggested in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/939832/524618). However, I have an issue with the `Enter` key: all I get is the bell in my shell.

When I try to set up a new key binding and hit the `Enter` key in the 'Keyboard Shortcut' text field, the symbol is exactly the same as for the `Return` key (i.e. no `num`-prefix). The `Return` key works as expected.

How do I get to send the numeric keypad `Enter` key to send `0x0D`?

Comment: Did you try this answer: http://superuser.com/a/565179/109692?