# Vim through Vnc: numpad keys inserting unexpected characters

Tags: linux, terminal, vim, vnc, numpad

This question dovetails from [How do I get the numpad to work in vim using iterm2 on osx with term=xterm?](https://superuser.com/questions/565178/how-do-i-get-the-numpad-to-work-in-vim-using-iterm2-on-osx-with-term-xterm) and [How do I get the numpad to work in vim using iterm2 on osx with term=xterm?](https://superuser.com/questions/565178/how-do-i-get-the-numpad-to-work-in-vim-using-iterm2-on-osx-with-term-xterm/939832#939832) but I couldn't find elements described in those respective answers.

I am accessing a Linux box through VNC from a Windows box.

On the Linux box, through this VNC session, I'm editing in Vim, and in insert mode, when I type '/' and '*' from the numeric keypad (i.e. to start a C-style comment), the characters 'o' and 'j' are inserted instead (specifically, a carriage return seems to be inserted, then the 'o' or 'j' is inserted at the first tab stop).

The questions and answers that I noted seem MacOs-specific; e.g. between the terminal running on the Linux box and VNC's Preferences, I couldn't find any reference to "xterm with Numeric Keypad".

Can someone advise how to fix this problem in my described environment? I'm unclear if the source of this behavior is Vim, the terminal, or VNC.

Here are `$TERM`, Vim version, and .vimrc, if they're relevant:

```
>vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Dec 21 2016 15:22:28)

>echo $TERM
screen-256color

>cat ~/.vimrc
set backspace=indent,eol,start
set shiftwidth=2
set softtabstop=2
set expandtab
set smarttab
filetype plugin indent on
autocmd FileType make set noexpandtab shiftwidth=4 softtabstop=0
set cino+=(0
set statusline=
set statusline +=\[%n] "buffer number
set statusline +=\%F   "File
set statusline +=%=%l/%L "currentLine/totalLine
set statusline +=%4v "virtual column
set laststatus=2
set t_Co=256
colorscheme torte
set number
"let g:netrw_liststyle = 3
syntax on
```

**Update:**
One other probably relevant factor: I am running tmux atop my bash shell. My .tmux.conf:

```
>cat ~/.tmux.conf 
unbind C-b
set -g prefix C-a
bind C-a send-prefix
set-window-option -g mode-keys vi
set -g set-titles on
set-window-option -g automatic-rename off
set-option -g allow-rename off
```

Comment: I have the same problem accessing a linux box from another linux box over vnc, and running vim within tmux. All of the factors need to be in place to see the issue, removing vnc / tmux / vim from the equation makes everything work. Temporarily removing both .tmux.conf and .vimrc makes no difference. By recording it as a macro, I discovered that the actual keystrokes that vim is receiving are `^[Oj`.

Comment: Investigation results: `/` and `*` do the same thing outside of vnc, when numlock is off. However, I tried turning numlock on within vnc (both via xset and passing through system keys), and although numlock is definitely on (number keys themselves work), `/` and `*` still have this weird behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

PS: I got this info on net and couldn’t find the source link now.

1. Create the following file in some common location:

   ```
   $ cat fix_numpad 
   ! initialization, 
   ! Ensure that we have all keysyms we're going to use assigned to something. 

   keycode any = KP_Insert 
   keycode any = KP_End 
   keycode any = KP_Down 
   keycode any = KP_Next 
   keycode any = KP_Left 
   keycode any = KP_Begin 
   keycode any = KP_Right 
   keycode any = KP_Home 
   keycode any = KP_Up 
   keycode any = KP_Prior 
   keycode any = KP_Delete 

   ! Set the keypad to numeric mode. 
   ! You may need to adjust KP_Next/KP_Prior; possible alternatives 
   ! are KP_Page_Down/KP_Page_Up or just Next/Prior. 
   ! just Next. 
   keysym KP_Insert = KP_0 
   keysym KP_End    = KP_1 
   keysym KP_Down   = KP_2 
   keysym KP_Next   = KP_3 
   keysym KP_Left   = KP_4 
   keysym KP_Begin  = KP_5 
   keysym KP_Right  = KP_6 
   keysym KP_Home   = KP_7 
   keysym KP_Up     = KP_8 
   keysym KP_Prior  = KP_9 
   keysym KP_Delete = KP_Decimal

   $
   ```
2. Assign the new mappings

   ```
   $ xmodmap fix_numpad
   ```

NOTE: You can add this to your `~/.vnc/xstartup` file so that your mappings are always retained.

Comment: Please try to find the source, and [edit] your answer to provide a link to it.

Comment: This looked promising, but alas, made no difference: the described problem is unchanged after creating a file with your posted content, and adding "`xmodmap fix_numpad`" to my `~/.vnc/xstartup`.

Comment: It is working flawlessly in my machine and here is my mappings: $xmodmap 
xmodmap:  up to 4 keys per modifier, (keycodes in parentheses):

shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock        Caps_Lock (0x42)
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_R (0x6d)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Alt_R (0x71),  Meta_L (0x9c)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3      
mod4        Super_L (0x73),  Super_R (0x74),  Super_L (0x7f),  Hyper_L (0x80)
mod5        Mode_switch (0x8),  ISO_Level3_Shift (0x7c)

Answer (score 0):

The question implies that you're using `xterm`, and want to turn the application keypad mode to *normal* (while it has been set to *application*).  For `xterm`, you can always turn the application modes on/off through a menu entry in the "VT Options" menu (control-middle-mouse click):

- [Enable application cursor keys](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT-Options:Enable-Application-Cursor-Keys)
- [Enable application keypad](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT-Options:Enable-Application-Keypad)

Those menu entries are selected (with a checkmark) when they are in *application mode*.

`xterm` uses the keycode information to tell it if a keypad key is pressed, and uses the normal/application mode to decide what to send for that key.

Answer (score 0):

The only way around this that I've found is to modify the `TERM` environment variable within tmux:

```
setenv TERM xterm
```

(I'm in tcsh, much to my dismay)

However, this is NOT a recommended long-term solution. [The tmux devs say display issues are likely to occur](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki/FAQ#what-is-term-and-what-does-it-do). It is behaving for me at the moment, but this is definitely going to be a "when required" thing: I would love to hear a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

i am using x11vnc as server and tigervnc as viewer. same problem.

i have fixed it with `setxkbmap -option 'numpad:microsoft'`.